# Javascript in Zapier to return multiple values for posting to Airtable database

Tags: javascript, zapier, airtable

I am trying to write some javascript in Zapier which will read two dates and then return an array of all dates between those dates in such a way that they can then be used to create multiple dated records in Airtable (a database). From the Zapier help it says that if you return an array of objects then the following steps will be processed for each.

I have managed to get code which returns the data I wan but it can't be correct because if I try to create the database records only one is created - with all the dates in (so it will only work if output to a text field - not a date). Here's my code attempt:

```
var fromDate = new Date(inputData.from);
var toDate = new Date(inputData.to);
var output =[];
var i = 1;
do {
    var useDate = new String(fromDate.toISOString())
    output.push(useDate);
    console.log(fromDate);
    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
    i++
}
while (fromDate <= toDate);
console.log(output);
return{output};
```

The subsequent step does see the output variable - but it is treated as one value as I said above.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Juan

That sorted it - or at least it did after removing the return - here is the working code:

```
var fromDate = new Date(inputData.from);
var toDate = new Date(inputData.to);
var output =[];
var i = 1;
do {
  var useDate = new String(fromDate.toISOString())
  var dateObject = {};
  dateObject.date = useDate;
  output.push({dateObject});
  fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
  i++
}
while (fromDate <= toDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning an object, not an array of objects:

`return{output};`

Also, your do/while statement is creating an array of strings, not objects. In your do block, instead of pushing the `useDate` string to the `output` array, you should construct a simple object and push *that* to the output array.

So instead of pushing `'2016-09-28T00:00:00.000Z'` each time the loop runs, you should push something like `{date: '2016-09-28T00:00:00.000Z'}`.

Your do block should look something like this:

```
do {
    var useDate = new String(fromDate.toISOString());
    var dateObject = {};
    dateObject.date = useDate;
    output.push(dateObject);
    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
    i++
}
```

This way, `output` will be an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-09-29T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```